# How to get coordinates of Run or other WordProcessing element via OpenXML?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I was wondering if it is possible to find the coordinates of a specific `Run` (text, no drawing or other elements that have offset parameter) on a page in a Word document using `OpenXML SDK`. I know that OpenXML is basically .. well XML, and simple runs have no relative, numerical position embedded in them.

I was reading through OpenXML SDK API and found no clues but maybe I have missed something. By coordinates I mean any tuple that can be mapped to pixels if I would generated an image out of the page (imagine you made a screenshot of page)

I suspect, if this is possible, it is not trivial.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Open XML SDK does not include this functionality. This would require a layout engine, which is not part of the SDK.

Comment: @Proko, thanks (and please also upvote if the answer is helpful). To add to that, the Open XML SDK is a very low-level library that just lets you process (create, change, delete) the Open XML parts and markup making up an Office document. There is no abstraction and there are no higher-level features.

Answer (score 2):

Word is not a page layout program, it's a word processor. Therefore:

No, it's not possible because...

The Word application dynamically lays out a page when it's opened in the Word application. Exactly how it's layed out and where things appear on-screen (or on the printed page) depends on how Word calculates font size as well as line, character and paragraph spacing (in all directions) for the currently selected printer driver. So it can vary and thus cannot be saved in the Open XML file.